# WPF C# and proper Architecture

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, architecture

I have been attempting to implement what I considered a very basic OOP implementation of a SCHOOL, CLASS, and STUDENT.

In this case I am working with a single SCHOOL, which contains a List<> of unique CLASSES, each CLASS contains a List<> of unique STUDENTS(Only one student named Jack/Amber/Paul per school, and each student is only taking one class).

[image]

This was easy to implement. My concern came when I attempted to make an editable WPF.

I want to create a WPF that allows the user to create classes, and students, modify data about them, and delete them. My problem is, I don't know where in the hierarchy it should go.

I can't tell if each CLASS and STUDENT should control their own Pop-Ups which edit their objects, or if there should be a controller that manages everything from the SCHOOL down (seem's like over kill).

```
Static class SCHOOL()
{
    List<CLASS> classes = new List<CLASS>();


}

public class CLASS()
{
    List<STUDENT> classes = new List<STUDNET>();
}

public class STUDENT()
{
    public STUDNET()
    {
        /* Open POP-UP which gives the user the
        ability to set the name, gpa, etc... of the student */
    }

    public void modifyData()
    {
        /* Open POP-UP which gives the user 
        the ability to set the name, gpa, etc... of the student */
    }
}
```

Am I approaching this the right way?

Comment: Can students edit their own data? (And get away with it)

Comment: @Jimenemex in this case it's not relevant. All the data will be output to a JSON file after the user has added everything they need.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really give us enough information about what you propose to comment fully, but your code shows that you have definitely got something wrong with your approach.

Classes like `School` and `Student` should **not** have any knowledge of editing, pop-ups (by which I assume you mean a details window) and so on. Model classes should only contain data (such as public and private variables), and behaviour (methods) that are specifically related to the class itself. For example, if a `Class` class had a public property for the list of students, you could add a method that returned the number of students taking the class. Even though this example is a bit pointless, it serves to demonstrate that the class's behaviour should only be that which is relevant to the model.

By contrast, a method of editing the data (such as a pop-up window) is specific to an application that uses the class. You don't wan the class to know about that.

Hope that helps.

By the way, a few small comments on your code...

- The general standard is for class names and public methods/properties to use CamelCase, eg `School`, `Student` etc. Uppercase is non-standard and should be avoided
- `Class` is a **really** bad choice of name for a class, as it's a reserved word (in lowercase), and could cause confusion.

Comment: @jcrash Did I answer your question? If so, please accept it. If not, please let me know if there's anything else you need to know